# Setup RISC-V toolchain with specific instruction set

Tags: toolchain, riscv, risc

I'm developing a processor using a form of the RISC-V ISA and i'm currently trying to setup the toolchain.
My current processor design uses the RV32I base instruction set and i want to compile for this ISA. However the default configuration of the toolchain, as written on the http://RISCV.org site, is to compile for the RV64I ISA.

How can i reconfigure this toolchain to produce a binary for the RV32I ISA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the RISC-V port of gcc, you can use the `-march` flag to constrain which instruction sets and extensions it will emit.

Example:

```
riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -march=RV32I etc.
```

The fact that the compiler name begins with `riscv64` is irrelevant. x86 is the same way (the x86 64bit compiler can generate 32-bit ia32 code via "-m32").